# Cannot Resolve MapODataRoute for a Web API OData Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to configure an OData endpoint for my Web API service and I can not resolve the `MapODataRoute` method. As per this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/getting-started-with-odata-in-web-api/create-a-read-only-odata-endpoint) the following is stated about the requirments:

> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update **or** the Microsoft ASP.NET Web API
>   OData NuGet package.

I have the current ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update installed (had uninstalled the RC version and installed the newest one), so my project should suffice.

However I can't get past the following line of code:

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
```

...due to the following exception:

> 'System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection' does not contain a definition
>   for 'MapODataRoute' and no extension method 'MapODataRoute' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I believe if I install the NuGet package this message would resolve (and it's no big deal to install it), **but I thought all the OData support was rolled up into the 'ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update'** thus not requiring the NuGet package? Does anyone know why `MapODataRoute` is not resolving or which reference I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same tutorial:

> If you installed ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update, then the Web API
>   project template automatically includes the OData packages.

So, check nuget packages of your project, whether odata packages are present.

May be, you installed new version of ASP.NET and Web Tools and then open your old project.
I suspect that you don't need manually add odata packages only if you create project after you installed ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update.

Comment: That has got to be the issue. Adding the NuGet package *did* solve the issue. As this solution was created prior to the Tools update, I'm sure it did not retrofit new packages. Makes total sense.

Answer (score 4):

For me none of the above solutions worked.

The `MapODataRoute` method is now deprecated. The way that worked perfectly for me was to do the following:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Supplier>("Suppliers");
        builder.EntitySet<Category>("Categories");
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");            
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "odata", routePrefix: "odata", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Note the different `MapODataServiceRoute` method.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add to install [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/) from nuget. Then make sure to include an using statement System.Web.Http to get the routes to work properly. Also make sure to add the routes to WebApiConfig.cs not RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
using APIOData.API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;

 static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
    builder.EntitySet<Category>("Categories");
    builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}

//www.api.com/odata/products
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("oData", GetEdmModel()).Filter().Select().Expand());
```

hope it helps